# React - UseState - How to partially update state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

## Problem

Hi,

I'm trying to partially update my state object :

```js
const [elephantProp, setElephantProp] = useState({
        name: "",
        color: "",
        size: "",
        race: "",
        country: "",
    });
```

Let's say I want to update only color and size parameters.

## What I have tried

### 1

Dynamically change parameters (according to the input object) :

```js
const handleChange = (input) => {
    Object.keys(input).forEach((key) => {
        setElephantProp({ ...elephantProp, [key]: input[key] });
    };
```

Output : change only last parameter (size).

### 2

Set all parameters at once :

```js
const handleChange = (input) => {
        setElephantProp({ ...elephantProp, color: input.color, size: input.size });
    };
```

Output : Works but is not dynamic (if I add a parameter to the input object there will be no effects)

Do you have any ideas on how to dynamically update some of my state variables ?

Maybe I should consider splitting into multiple state variables (not convenient with a lot of variables) or using nested objects ?

Comment: setElephantProp is Async method that's why this happening. When you are looping through it you not get the state updated value. so last value get updating. Can you please try the same with for loop it sync and forEach is Async. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From you code I am going to assume that `input` is an object representing the state updates, e.g.

```
{
    name: "Dumbo",
    country: "USA"
}
```

In this case you can simply do:

```
const handleChange = (input) => {
    setElephantProp({ ...elephantProp, ...input });
}
```

As `...input` come last, its properties will overwrite `elephantProp` properties that have the same key.
Please notice in this way all `input` keys which are not present in `elephantProp`, will be added to the state; e.g.

```js
const elephantProp = {
  name: "",
  color: "",
  size: "",
  race: "",
  country: "",
};

const input = {
  name: "Dumbo",
  country: "USA",
  ableToFly: true,
};

const updatedElephantProp = {
  ...elephantProp,
  ...input
} // => the updated state will contain the key/value pair 'ableToFly: true' too

console.log(updatedElephantProp)
```

This behaviour might be desirable or not, depending on your needs and project specifications.

Comment: Thanks ! It perfectly fit my needs as I control what can be stored in the input object.

Now my handleChange function looks like this : 

`
const handleChange = (input) => {
  setElephantProp({ ...elephantProp, ...input });
 };
`

Answer (score 1):

You can use concept `useReducer` - is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values - [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

```
    const [changes, onChange] = useReducer((value, change) => ({...(value || {}), ...change}), {});

    //used
    const {name, color, size, race, country} = changes;
    
    const handleChange = change => {
        //example change = {name: 'alex'}
        onChange(change);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

React recommends using multiple states for the different variables.
However, if you did want to set a full object, you'd likely rather copy the object, and `setState` only once. You loop might not be caught properly by the rerendering, as it is an async function.

I'm not sure what your implementation is, but something like this should work:

```
const handleChange = (objectIn) => {
  // create a new object merging the old one and your input
  const newElephant = {
    ...elephantProps,
    ...objectIn
  }
  setElephantProps(newElephant)
}
```

This should handle your case gracefully. If you're using multiple inputs, I usually handle it that way:

```
  const onChange = ({ target: { value, name } }) => setElephant({
    ...elephant,
    [name]: value
  })
  return <input onChange={onChange} name="size" value={elephant.size} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass 2-nd param to handleChange, for example:

```
const handleChange = (input, name) => {
    setElephantProp({ ...elephantProp, [name]: input[name] });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your solutions [here: codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-hofstadter-cbhl6?file=/src/App.js:99-1197)  or bellow code using this approach.

```
  const onChangeHandaller = (e) => {
    setElephantProp({ ...elephantProp, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

[image]

```
const [elephantProp, setElephantProp] = useState({
    name: "",
    color: "",
    size: "",
    race: "",
    country: ""
  });

  const onChangeHandaller = (e) => {
    setElephantProp({ ...elephantProp, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Name:{" "}
      <input
        value={elephantProp.name}
        name="name"
        onChange={(e) => onChangeHandaller(e)}
      />{" "}
      <br />
      Color:{" "}
      <input
        value={elephantProp.color}
        name="color"
        onChange={(e) => onChangeHandaller(e)}
      />{" "}
      <br />
      Size:{" "}
      <input
        value={elephantProp.size}
        name="size"
        onChange={(e) => onChangeHandaller(e)}
      />{" "}
      <br />
      Race:{" "}
      <input
        value={elephantProp.race}
        name="race"
        onChange={(e) => onChangeHandaller(e)}
      />{" "}
      <br />
      Country:{" "}
      <input
        value={elephantProp.country}
        name="country"
        onChange={(e) => onChangeHandaller(e)}
      />{" "}
      <br />
    </div>
```